# Group Set Should Not Appear if "Checked In"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So I currently have this query that works great - expect there is a wee bit of a change I'd like to carry out.  If a Group ID has successful Checkins from a different SiteID then the entirety of that Group ID with all it's SiteIDs should not show up in my query (since mine is just capturing non-"Checked in" peeps).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    min(sa.SiteID) as SiteId,
    s.GroupID,
    u.UserFirstName,
    u.UserLastName,
    convert(varchar,sa.StartDateTime,101) as ApptStartDate,
    cast(sa.StartDateTime as Time) as ApptStartTime,
    convert(varchar,sa.EndDateTime,101) as ApptEndDate,
    cast(sa.EndDateTime as Time) as ApptEndTime,
    psn.ProjectSubName,
    convert(varchar,saa.Date,101) as ArrivalDate,
    cast(saa.Time as Time) as ArrivalTime
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON sas.ScannerUserID = u.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectSubNames psn ON s.ProjectSubID=psn.ProjectSubID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
    and saa.ScannerUserID=sas.ScannerUserID
WHERE 
    saa.Date is null
    AND s.ProjectID=110
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101 ) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,StartDateTime  ,101 )
GROUP BY
    u.UserFirstName,
    u.UserLastName,
    s.GroupID,
    convert(varchar,sa.StartDateTime,101),
    cast(sa.StartDateTime as Time),
    convert(varchar,sa.EndDateTime,101),
    cast(sa.EndDateTime as Time),
    psn.ProjectSubName,
    convert(varchar,saa.Date,101),
    cast(saa.Time as Time) 
ORDER BY 
    SiteId
```

So just for further clarification I'll set up a simple table of info

```
Group ID | Site ID | Arrival Time
---------------------------------
12345    | 23456   | 06:00 AM 
---------------------------------
12345    | 34567   | NULL
---------------------------------
12345    | 45678   | 06:00 AM 
--------------------------------
67890    | 56789   | 06:30 AM
```

So basically you can have multiple siteids assigned to one group id.  As demonstrated above, if the group has an arrival time (12345 - 6 AM) but one of the sites within that group is `NULL` then it should still mark that site within that group as "Checked in" even though the date is `NULL`.

Right now my query is picking up that NULL value, when I don't want it to be picked up at all since it's Group has other sites that are checked in.

Comment: Change the `left join` to an `inner join` to only return ones that have checked in? (I may have misunderstood the question however :D)

Comment: lol - the inner join doesn't produce the non-checked in rows that I'm looking for :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a `having` clause:

```
having sum(case when saa.Date is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Also, two other suggestions:

1. `select distinct` is almost never needed with `group by`.  You should remove it and fix the logic if it is actually doing anything.
2. When using `varchar`, always specify a length.  The default length varies by context, so using the length is the safest approach.  Your `convert()` calls should be something like `convert(varchar(255), . . .)`.

EDIT:

In that case, we have to resort to a slightly different solution, still using the `having` clause.  Add the following to your `select`:

```
sum(case when convert(varchar(255), saa.Date, 101) is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by GroupId) as sumgroup
```

And then change the `having` clause to:

```
having sumgroup = 1;
```

It was fully clear to me what you meant by group.  I took a stab thinking that it was the groups generated by `group by`.  This defines a `group` based on the `GroupId` column.

Comment: I'm not looking for a sum of "non-checked in" sites. So I'm not sure how sum is being utilized here?

Comment: This implements the logic described in your question:  "If a Group ID has successful Checkins from a different SiteID then the entirety of that Group ID with all it's SiteIDs should not show up in my query".  It counts the number of values that are not NULL, if there are any, then the row(s) are filtered out.

Comment: Hmm - using the having clause seems to still produce those NULL values.  I pretty much kept everything the same (using your suggestions about Distinct and Varchar) and added in the having clause after the Group By clause.